# ERROR in ./node_modules/query-string/base.js

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, ionic-framework, webpack

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (470:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

return {
        url: url_?.split('?')?.[0] ?? '',
        query: parse(extract(url), options),
        ...(options && options.parseFragmentIdentifier && hash ? {fragmentIdentifier: decode(hash, options)} : {}),
```

I have already tried adding the below in my `angular.json` file, but it didn't work:

```json
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/query-string/base.js"
           ]
```

My build is failing and I am using Angular 10.

Comment: Optional chaining is something that came out with ES2020, you will need to make sure your build system understands this.   I don't use angular, but from what I can gather it uses Typescript, so you should be able to alter your `tsconfig.json` file and set `lib: ['dom', 'es2020']`

Comment: this did not work